# Utilidade do operador de coerção reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, operadores, cast

Para que serve o operador de coerção `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: Agora você já pode votar em tudo no site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conhece o [*cast*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) de outras linguagens, especialmente do C? O *cast* é justamente uma indicação para tratar um dado de um tipo como outro tipo, você muda uma característica a ser vista naquele objeto. Em alguns casos isso passa por converter o valor, porque esse valor tem outro tamanho e/ou codificação de bits. Há casos que não precisa mudar nada, só precisa fazer desta forma para indicar ao compilador que você sabe o que está fazendo e é exatamente o que deseja, que você sabe mais que ele sobre o contexto.

Em C++ prefere-se, embora o jeito do C ainda funcione, usar *casts* específicos para cada situação deixando claro semanticamente o que se deseja, e que o código demonstre que operação está sendo feita. Existe alguns *casts*, tais como: [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) e [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

O [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), como o nome diz, é só uma indicação para o compilador que o tipo a ser considerado ali naquele ponto do código é diferente do tipo real do dado. Indica que você sabe que o dado é de outro tipo do que o esperado naquele ponto e sabe que o dado se encaixa bem onde será usado do jeito que ele está.

O compilador normalmente barraria a compilação dando erro porque ele sabe que são tipos diferentes, mas ele não sabe tanto quanto você e não pode considerar isto automaticamente ([alguns tipos ele sabe](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) sim, por exemplo ele sabe que um `short` pode ser usando onde se espera um `int`, ou um `Cachorro` pode ser usado em vários lugares onde se espera um `Animal` (considerando que um herda do outro).

A documentação *linkada* tem a descrição dos casos que funciona e é adequado e exemplo de uso.